# OpenGL 2D Evaluator Mesh cannot set larger

Tags: opengl, 2d, mesh, evaluator

I have this OpenGL project I'm working on that involves creating a 2D flat mesh to mess around with. The code is as such:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glut.h>

GLfloat ctrlpoints[9][9][3] = {
    {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 0}, {8, 0, 0}},
    {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 0}, {5, 1, 0}, {6, 1, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {8, 1, 0}},
    {{0, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {3, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 0}, {5, 2, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 2, 0}},
    {{0, 3, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 0}, {3, 3, 0}, {4, 3, 0}, {5, 3, 0}, {6, 3, 0}, {7, 3, 0}, {8, 3, 0}},
    {{0, 4, 0}, {1, 4, 0}, {2, 4, 0}, {3, 4, 0}, {4, 4, 0}, {5, 4, 0}, {6, 4, 0}, {7, 4, 0}, {8, 4, 0}},
    {{0, 5, 0}, {1, 5, 0}, {2, 5, 0}, {3, 5, 0}, {4, 5, 0}, {5, 5, 0}, {6, 5, 0}, {7, 5, 0}, {8, 5, 0}},
    {{0, 6, 0}, {1, 6, 0}, {2, 6, 0}, {3, 6, 0}, {4, 6, 0}, {5, 6, 0}, {6, 6, 0}, {7, 6, 0}, {8, 6, 0}},
    {{0, 7, 0}, {1, 7, 0}, {2, 7, 0}, {3, 7, 0}, {4, 7, 0}, {5, 7, 0}, {6, 7, 0}, {7, 7, 0}, {8, 7, 0}},
    {{0, 8, 0}, {1, 8, 0}, {2, 8, 0}, {3, 8, 0}, {4, 8, 0}, {5, 8, 0}, {6, 8, 0}, {7, 8, 0}, {8, 8, 0}}
};

void init(void)
{
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
   glMap2f(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3, 0, 1, 3, 9, 0, 1, 27, 9, &ctrlpoints[0][0][0]);
   glEnable(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void display(void)
{
    int i, j;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPushMatrix ();
    gluLookAt(10,10,10, 0,0,0, 0,0,1);

    /**** We have the option to use this method rather than dealilng with nasty loops *****/
    glMapGrid2f(  50, 0.0, 1.0,  50, 0.0, 1.0);
    glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);   //this line calculates all normal vectors for the mesh. It has to be commented in when lighting is enabled.

    //glEvalMesh2(GL_LINE, 0, 50, 0, 50);  //This defines a mesh that 5 by 6 vetrices defined by our evaluator defined above
    glEvalMesh2(GL_FILL, 0, 50, 0, 50); //This one fills the the mesh
    /******************************************************/
    glPopMatrix ();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(-10, 10, -10, 10, 0.1, 30);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}

void initlights(void)
{
   GLfloat ambient[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
   GLfloat position[] = {1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0};
   GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
   GLfloat mat_specular[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0};
   GLfloat mat_shininess[] = {50.0};

   glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
   glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

   glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
   glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);

   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
   init ();
   initlights();
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;
}
```

**GLfloat ctrlpoints** is array that determines how big the mesh is and the coordinates of each point. **glMap2f** must be changed to accommodate the array, which I believe I have used correctly.  Right now it's is 9x9. However, nothing is showing up when I try running the program. What's really strange however is that if I make ctrlpoints smaller, such as 8x8:

```
GLfloat ctrlpoints[8][8][3] = {
    {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 0}},
    {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 0}, {5, 1, 0}, {6, 1, 0}, {7, 1, 0}},
    {{0, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {3, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 0}, {5, 2, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {7, 2, 0}},
    {{0, 3, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 0}, {3, 3, 0}, {4, 3, 0}, {5, 3, 0}, {6, 3, 0}, {7, 3, 0}},
    {{0, 4, 0}, {1, 4, 0}, {2, 4, 0}, {3, 4, 0}, {4, 4, 0}, {5, 4, 0}, {6, 4, 0}, {7, 4, 0}},
    {{0, 5, 0}, {1, 5, 0}, {2, 5, 0}, {3, 5, 0}, {4, 5, 0}, {5, 5, 0}, {6, 5, 0}, {7, 5, 0}},
    {{0, 6, 0}, {1, 6, 0}, {2, 6, 0}, {3, 6, 0}, {4, 6, 0}, {5, 6, 0}, {6, 6, 0}, {7, 6, 0}},
    {{0, 7, 0}, {1, 7, 0}, {2, 7, 0}, {3, 7, 0}, {4, 7, 0}, {5, 7, 0}, {6, 7, 0}, {7, 7, 0}}
};
```

and modify glMap2f as such

```
glMap2f(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3, 0, 1, 3, 8, 0, 1, 24, 8, &ctrlpoints[0][0][0]);
```

The mesh suddenly appears on the screen! It worked if I went lower as well, like 7x7.

What exactly is going on here? How come if I try making the mesh bigger then 8x8, it doesn't appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `GL_MAX_EVAL_ORDER` is greater than 8.  Evaluators are old and janky so I wouldn't be surprised if your OpenGL implementation only provided the minimum required (8).

You can retrieve the value of `GL_MAX_EVAL_ORDER` via [`glGet()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glGet.xml).

You can also check `glGetError()` for `GL_INVALID_VALUE` after your `glMap2f()` call.

Comment: Thank you. I used glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_EVAL_ORDER, &result) to see that my evaluator was 8. It appears I'll need to write my own evaluator to change it... What's strange is that my colleague used the similar code and got larger meshes just fine.

Comment: Was your colleague running on a workstation-class card (AMD FireGL, Nvidia Quadro, etc.) and drivers?